# error In using math function in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

When I am passing constant value in log2() as follow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
int var;
var= log2(16);
printf("%d",var);
return 0;
}
```

gcc prog.c (NO Error)
4

But when I am passing variable in function log2(var) gives error
undefined reference to `log2' I require to link library i.e. -lm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
int var,i;
i= log2(var);
printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

Gives error

```
undefined reference to `log2'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first piece of code, the compiler replaces `log2(16)` with the constant `4`. The compiler usually optimizes constant math this way. That's the reason you don't see an error.

See the generated code for confirmation. This is for your first version:

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $4, 28(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

There is no call to log2. The compiler already replaced it by the constant 4 (`movl    $4, 28(%esp)`).

This one is for your second version:

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $48, %esp
    fildl   40(%esp)
    fstpl   (%esp)
    call    log2
    fnstcw  30(%esp)
    movzwl  30(%esp), %eax
    movb    $12, %ah
    movw    %ax, 28(%esp)
    fldcw   28(%esp)
    fistpl  44(%esp)
    fldcw   30(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    44(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

As you can see there is a `call log2` in this version. Thats why `-lm` is needed for the second version.

Comment: I've try to compile (using `-std=c99`) the example above using gcc builtin `log2()`. It didn't compile! I think, builtin functions works only with constants. Also it's weird, but there is no mention about `log2()` in `/usr/include/math.h`.